# Docker - Can mount an NFS share into a container but not a sub-directory of it

Tags: docker, nfs

I have an NFS share with the following properties:

- Mounted on my host on `/nfs/external_disk`
- Owner user is `test_user` with `UID 1234`
- Group is `test_group` with `GID 2222`
- Permissions is `750`

I have a small Dockerfile with the following content

```
ARG tag=lts
from jenkins/jenkins:${tag}

user root

# Create a new user and new group that matches what is on the host.
ARG username=test_user
ARG groupname=test_group
ARG uid=1234
ARG gid=2222
RUN groupadd -g ${gid} ${groupname} && \
    mkdir -p /users && \
    useradd -l -m -u ${uid} -g ${groupname} -s /bin/bash -d /users/${username} ${username}

user ${username}
```

After building the image (named `custom_jenkins`), and when I run the following command, the container is started properly and I see the original Jenkins homer stuff now copied to the share.

`docker run -td --rm -v /nfs/external_disk:/var/jenkins_home custom_jenkins`

However if I want to mount a sub-directory of the NFS share, say `${NFS_SHARE}/jenkins_home`, then I get an error:

`docker run -td --rm -v /nfs/external_disk/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home custom_jenkins`

> docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/nfs/external_disk/jenkins_home': mkdir /nfs/external_disk/jenkins_home: permission denied.

Now even if I attempt to create the sub-directory myself before starting the container, I still get the same error. Even when I set the permissions of the sub-directory to be `777`.

Note that I am running as `test_user` which has the same UID/GID as in the container and it actually owns the NFS share.

I have a feeling that when docker attempts to create a sub-directory, it attempts to create it as some different user (e.g. the "docker" user) which causes it to fail while creating the folder since it has no access inside the share.

Can anyone help? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try to add the --user <UID of the owner of the NFS from the host OS> to the docker run command?
I have a guess, but please confirm if this does the job ;) 
docker run -td --rm --user 1234 -v /nfs/external_disk/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home custom_jenkins

Comment: Hi, Neo, I can't speak for the O.P., but I have a similar case and we include '--user' for a user who owns the NFS directory.  I get the same error as the O.P.  Is that what you mean?  Note that 'root' does not have access to this directory.  I tried: docker run --rm -it -v <nfs_path_that_root_cannot_access>:<path_in_container> --user <id>:<gid> ubuntu /bin/bash

Comment: Hey @austinMLB, I tried to reproduce and everything works just fine for me. Perhaps I am missing some constraint that you have. I am describing the steps I performed in an answer, for better formatiing

Comment: I ended up mounting the entire share and created a symlink inside the container

Comment: @user3396919 You can add your own answer with the detailed commands you have used, and even accept your own answer. That will help others.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce. Works just fine for me. Perhaps I am missing some constraint. Hope this helps anyway. Note at step 6 the owner and the group for the file that I created from the container. This might answer one of your questions.

**Step 1:** I created a NFS share somewhere in my LAN
**Step 2:** I mounted the share on the machine that's running the docker engine

```
sudo mount 192.168.0.xxx:/i-data/b4024d5b/nfs/NFS /mnt/nsa320/
```

```
neo@neo-desktop:nsa320$ mount | grep NFS
192.168.0.xxx:/i-data/b4024d5b/nfs/NFS on /mnt/nsa320 type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.0.xxx,mountvers=3,mountport=3775,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.0.xxx)
```

**Step 3:** I created some sample files and a sub-directory:

```
neo@neo-desktop:nsa320$ ls -la /mnt/nsa320/
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jul 21 22:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul 21 22:41 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo  neo     0 Jul 21 22:45 dummyFile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jul 21 22:53 fileCreatedFromContainer << THIS WAS CREATED FROM A CONTAINER THAT WAS NOT LAUNCHED WITH THE --user OPTION
drwxr-xr-x 2 neo  neo  4096 Jul 21 22:54 subfolder
```

**Step 4:** Launched a dummy container and mounted the sub-directory (1000 is the UID of the user `neo` in the my OS):

```
docker run -d -v /mnt/nsa320/subfolder:/var/externalMount --user 1000 alpine tail -f /dev/null
```

**Step 5:** Connected in container to check the mount(I can read and write in the subfolder located on the NFS)

```
neo@neo-desktop:nsa320$ docker exec -ti ded1dc79773e sh
/ $ ls /var/externalMount/
fileInSubfolder
/ $ touch /var/externalMount/fileInSubfolderCreatedFromContainer
```

**Step 6:** Back on the host, to whom does the file that I created from the container belongs to:

```
neo@neo-desktop:nsa320$ ls -la /mnt/nsa320/subfolder/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 neo  neo  4096 Jul 21 23:23 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jul 21 22:54 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo  neo     0 Jul 21 22:54 fileInSubfolder
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo  root    0 Jul 21 23:23 fileInSubfolderCreatedFromContainer
```

**Maybe off-topic**: whoami executed in the container returns just the UID:

```
$ whoami
whoami: unknown uid 1000
```

Comment: Hi, Neo, thanks for the work trying to reproduce.  I will note that in our case "root" does not have access to the subfolder.  I'm not familiar enough with NFS to know the details of "root squash".  Based on this and the permission error we see, I was guessing Docker was "root" or some other local account at some point doing the actual mount.  That is, the user in my "--user <id>" has access to the NFS directory, so if that user were the only one in play, I don't see why we'd get a permission error.  I'm not sure if "root squash" is the difference between our setup and yours , or not.

Comment: Hi @austinMLB, I agree with your comment - `root squash` might be the only difference. I'm not a NAS expert either, just a developer but perhaps you have access to your NAS to have a look how it is configured on the server side. Here is some interesting documentation, under `User ID Mapping` -  https://linux.die.net/man/5/exports. I'd bet that config could be the key to this problem. Good luck and thanks for your reply and feedback!

Comment: Docker starts with user root and mounts the NFS shares into the container. Your /mnt/nsa320/ has 777 permissions, meaning also root has access. Then the container continues with the specified --user. This would not be possible if your NFS subfolder would have <772 permissions.